# One of my favorites

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This is not one of my originals, but It is one of my favorites. No looking it up!

> Only one color, yet not one size.
>
> Stuck at the bottom, yet easily flies.
>
> Present in sun, but not in rain,
>
> Doing no harm, and feeling no pain.

What am I?

Comment: Agreed, this one is one of my favorites.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Mine, too. Short and sweet... but I do like the long ones, too :) ..... **Edit:** Wow, that sounds wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this

> a shadow?

Only one color, yet not one size.

> Shadows vary in size, but they're all black.

Stuck at the bottom, yet easily flies.

> It's stuck to your feet, but it moves all over the place.

Present in sun, but not in rain,

> Light is needed for shadows.

Doing no harm, and feeling no pain.

> Tell that to the Doctor, and River Song. (Spoilers!)

Comment: Yep! I know it is a popular one, but I figured I would toss it on here.

Comment: Would like to point out liquid sunshine. :D Great riddle, great answer! +1